# How to create a editable dropdown list ? with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with 'select' html tag , however , this made the input box impossible to edit.

```
  <select name="blabla" id="search_container">
    <option>blabla</option>
    ...
  </select>
```

So i added an preceding input:

```
<input type=text value="" onkeyup="searchFilter()"> Search </input>
```

And when user input anything inside that box , `searchFilter()` will fire,  returns a set of `<option>` , overrides `search_container`.

But this makes the interface looks bad , i got two horizontal box here , but i did see many websites holds only one box , when user inputs , a list of option drops down , and you just pick one.

Thanks for any responses here.

@update , the term is called 'autocomplete' , and my problem is resolved. Thanks all

Comment: are you looking to implement something like this?     http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/               autocomplete?

Comment: JQuery has a nice [Live Search](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/) plugin that sounds like it does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about combobox with autocomplete - the one that allows typing in it an provides a list of options like so:

[image]

or this:

[image]

?

This is something that is quite complicated to achieve in pure JavaScript (although possible) and is normally achieved by using third-party JavaScript framework, that provides these out of the box.

You can take a look at the following JavaScript frameworks:

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)(perhaps requires a plugin)

[ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to create an "autocomplete" search box?

There are many options out there (just try googling "javascript autocomplete").

jQuery UI has this functionality available http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/, might be a good place to start.